# Java Image, after scaled get black color, how to make it white?

Tags: java, image-processing

I try to scale image to 50x50 px, but I got black color. I need to make black to white

[image]
after scaled
[image: Before scaled]

this my code:

```
BufferedImage imgs = urlToBufferImage("src//imgTest.jpg");
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(50, 50, imgs.getType());
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
// g.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
// g.drawImage(imgs, 0, 0, 50, 50,Color.WHITE, null);
g.drawImage(imgs.getScaledInstance(50, -1, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT), 0, 0, this);
g.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple.
My approach would be not to create a new BufferedImage, but to do:

```
BufferedImage imgs = urlToBufferImage("src//imgTest.jpg");
Graphics g = imgs.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(imgs, x, y, 50, 50, null);
```

or instead of drawing the image inside of the bounds, you could do

```
Graphics2D g2d = imgs.createGraphics();
g2d.scale(0.5, 0.5);
g2d.drawImage(imgs, x, y, null);
```